# Pass image byte array as json from android application to c# restful service

Tags: java, android, web-services

I need to upload an image from my android application by calling restful webservice in c#,But when i try it by adding byte[] to JSONObject,it converts the byte[] to string and the c# service throws Bad request("Error deserializing the Object.Element from namespace '' expected.Found text'[B@22b6cc7f'.

```
Android Code:
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ttulips);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

            JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
            try {
            jsonParam.put("IncomingFile",bitMapData);               
            jsonParam.put("FileName", "name.jpg");

            Log.d("Json",jsonParam+"");
} catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The log of JSON request is coming as
       {"IncomingFile":"[B@22b67f","FileName":"name.jpg"}

Even tried converting the byte array to Base64 encoded byte array,but while adding base64 byte array to jsonobject,it is taken as string.

How should I solve this issue?Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is wrong with a Base64 encoded string? This should be your choice

Comment: JSON only supports limited value types (strings, numbers, booleans and null). So you'll somehow have to convert the byte array to a string and deserialize accordingly

Comment: Thank you for your response.My c# service is expecting byte[].So is there any option to send byte[] instead of String?Otherwise the service need to be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this convert bitmap to string and pass this string to c# server

```
 if(fileUri1 != null) {
                bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri1.getPath(),
                        options);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                if(bitmap1 != null) {
                    bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, baos1);
                    byte[] b1 = baos1.toByteArray();
                    bitmapstring1 = Base64.encodeToString(b1, 

                    Base64.DEFAULT);
                }
            }
```

webservice call:

```
 public class CallWebService extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Call Webservice for Get Menus
        WebServiceCall webServiceCall = new WebServiceCall(); // Custom class for call webservice
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 8;


        parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name",uname12));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Address", uaddr12));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", en));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Qualification", uquali12));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Phoneno", ucontactno12));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Appliedfor", uappfor12));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Image", bitmapstring));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Resumeimage", bitmapstring1));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Operation", "i"));
        Log.i("param::",parameters.toString());
        response = webServiceCall.makeServiceCall(mUrlWebServiceLogin, parameters);


        Log.d("ResponseLogin:", response);



        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        if(response.contains("\"success\"")){
            session.createLoginSession(uname12);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successfully inserted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),InterView.class);
            in.putExtra("Name",uname12);

            startActivity(in);
            finish();


        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"data not inserted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Base64` on both sides, actually converting `byte[]` to `String` isn't the main problem
[read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285367/sending-image-with-byte-array-convertion-from-java-to-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

> Try below for creating JSON:

```
 String json = "{\"IncomingFile\":\""+ new String(bytesEncoded) +"\",\"FileName\":\""+name.jpg+"\"}";
```

> Where `bytesEncoded` should be Base64 encoded image.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the solution.I tried this solution and its showing invalid character '.'.Should the service be expecting byte array or String?

Comment: remove '.' from the json, and yes service should be expecting String only, as how can you pass bytes in json, eventually it's gonna be string right?

Answer (score -1):

here the object `bitMapData` is a bytearray and must be converted to String then you must use in the Json Object 
`jsonParam.put("IncomingFile",new String(bitMapData));`

Comment: No need for a JSON array here ... a byte array fits very well into a single string

Comment: _a small missunderstanding bro.. ur correct_ @devnull69